# What is the meaning of "They fought so hard over who was to be king that the island broke in two"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "They fought so hard over who was to be king
that the island broke in two" in the following sentences,

> Up from the sea came not a fish, but a huge island. The island was the
>   home of the mighty sea god. When the four older brothers saw the
>   beautiful island, each one wanted to be its king, and they started to
>   fight. They fought so hard over who was to be king that the island
>   broke in two, and all the lazy brothers were drowned.

Does it mean "They who wanted to be king fought turning the wheel 
that the island broke in two ?

What does "so hard over" mean ?

Comment: Where does a wheel come in?

Comment: I have searched the meaning of " hard over " in dictionary. at dictionary, I see that "hard over" mean "HARD OVER: Turning the wheel as far as possible or Hard over :
To steer the vessel as sharply as possible in either direction by turning the wheel or positioning the tiller as far as possible.".

Comment: As the answers explain, "hard over" is not a phrase in the sentence - it's just a sequence of words that happen to come together. But I now understand why you talked about a wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"So hard over" is not a phrase, or even a constituent of the sentence - it's just a sequence of words that happens to occur in the sentence.

> They fought over (i.e. about the question of) who was to be king.
>
> How hard did they fight? So hard that the island broke in two.

Answer (score 2):

The whole expression is "to fight over something". It means to contend/compete.

How do they fight? Hard.
Over what do they fight? Becoming king.

As consequence of their fighting (because they fight so hard), the island breaks in two (pieces).

Answer (score 0):

They differed and maybe competed on who was to be king. As they couldn't reach a common sense , the island fell apart.